# Have C-compare functions to be symmetric

Tags: c, binary-search

Compare functions for C's `bsearch` have two arguments type casted to `void *`. Does the standard demand for the first one being the key and the second one being the data element?

This is relevant, if the compare function takes different types for key and value. Recently I saw code like the following:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int key;
    char *value;
} record;

int cmp_find(const void *val, const void *key) {
    return strcmp((char *)val, ((record *)key)->value);
}
```

along with a custom search function with a similar signature like the original `bsearch`. This happened to crash if I used a `bsearch`-compare function.

Does the standard even allow `bsearch`-compare functions with different value types?

Comment: have you just copied and pasted your homework here?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: This is not my homework

Comment: It's in every description of the `bsearch` function. Being able to move arguments around at your whim is *not* an option in C.

Comment: @Jongware: I saw that implementation of a search function (`bsearch2`) and wanted to know if I might talk to my collegue to change the order required by `bsearch2` to be compatible with `bsearch`. If `bsearch` didn't allow different argument types, there would be no use to change the order in the implementation of `bsearch2`.

Comment: `(record *)key.value` should be `((record *)key)->value`, otherwise you would get a compiler error: `error: request for member ‘value’ in something not a structure or union`

Comment: @mch: Of course, corrected the typo

Comment: now the cast should be on `key`, not on `key->value`, look at the extra parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. From n1570 (C99+amendments / C11):

> #### 7.22.5 Searching and sorting utilities
>
> 2 The implementation shall ensure that the second argument of the comparison function
>   (when called from `bsearch`), or both arguments (when called from `qsort`), are
>   pointers to elements of the array.<sup>302)</sup> The first argument when called from `bsearch`
>   shall equal `key`.